# Terminate Conversation with Pending Callbacks

Tags: node.js, botframework

Is there any way or method to abruptly stop the bot's dialog/conversation when it typed 'stop' together with any pending callbacks within a waterfall step?

There is handling for 'stop' built-in, but it just stops the waterfall from proceeding.

Given the scenario of a waterfall dialog, `stepA` → `stepB` → `stepC`. The dialog starts at `stepA`, proceeds to `stepB` which calls a HTTP request with a callback, before the request finished and before proceeding to `stepC`, user types `stop`, ends the dialog, however, within `stepB`, there is a code on the callback `session.send(output)`. This will get sent regardless if I already stopped the the dialog.

Note: I'm still using V1. Seeing V3 has `endConversation`, it doesn't still work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking a similar question and the only answer I got is just to delete all conversation data or user data. This may remove useful info that you have stored, too.

Comment: I see. That however does not make any pending callback from sending back. The weird part is. You already ended the session, so the assumption is that using that same session should be void.